# how to write a loop that sorts numbers by odd, even, and zero from random numbers

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to write a program in C++ that will generate a random number for each type of loop a random amount of times a sort the numbers by odd even and zero 
what i have so far will run as many times as the while limit and by default always add to the odd value, any idea what's wrong with my code?

```
int main()
{
//establishes variables needed
int whilelimit, whilevalue, whileodd = 0, whileeven = 0, whilezero = 0, 
forlimit, forodd = 0, foreven = 0, forzero = 0, forvalue, dowhilelimit, 
dowhilevalue, dowhileodd = 0, dowhileeven = 0, dowhilezero = 0;
srand(time(NULL));
//while loop
whilelimit = rand() % 18 + 2;
whilevalue = rand() % 100 + 0;
while (whilelimit > 0)
{
// determine if the value is even odd or zero
    if (whilevalue != 0)
    {
        if (whilevalue / 2 != 0 )
        {
            whileodd++;
        }
        else if (whilevalue / 2 == 0)
        {
            whileeven++;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        whilezero++;
    }
    whilelimit--;
}
cout << "Zero: " << whilezero << "even: " << whileeven << "odd: " << 
whileodd << endl;
//for loop
//do while loop



system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: pretty simple whilevalue never changes....

Comment: Find a good debugger for your system and learn how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a modulus "%" as your check for odd or even instead of "/". The modulus give you the remainder of a division. That's what you're checking for 0 with to determine if a value is divisible by another number. Also this is a hw question. Go back into the chapter that it covers and find where it covers the modulus and read up on it.

Answer (score 2):

as @epascarello mentioned, your whilevalue never changes.  Try moving it into the loop:

```
whilelimit = rand() % 18 + 2;
while (whilelimit > 0)
{
    whilevalue = rand() % 100 + 0;
    //other code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be % not / 
Currently you are just adding to odd because it is seeing if the number is divisible by 2 and not equal to zero which is true for most numbers.

```
while (whilelimit > 0)

    {
    // determine if the value is even odd or zero
        if (whilevalue != 0)
        {
            if (whilevalue % 2 != 0 )
            {
                whileodd++;
            }
            else if (whilevalue % 2 == 0)
            {
                whileeven++;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            whilezero++;
        }
        whilelimit--;
    }
```

Comment: `if (whilevalue % 2 == 0)`part is useless as a number is either odd or even.

Comment: `whileeven` would have the exact same value without the redundant check.

Comment: Oh that's what you mean. I just copied the OP's code and changed the necessary symbol I didn't feel the need to optimize it to answer this particular question.

Comment: but yes you are correct the second check is redundant

Answer (score 1):

It's good to seed the `rand()` function with the current time using `srand()`. Also make sure to change the `whileValue` everytime.

```
srand(time(NULL));
int whileLimit = (rand() % 18) + 2;

unsigned numZeros = 0, numEvens = 0, numOdds = 0;
while(whileLimit-- > 0) {
    int whileValue = rand() % 100;

    // Assuming zero is not an even number
    if (!whileValue) {
        ++numZeros;
        continue;
    }

    ++((whileValue % 2) ? numOdds : numEvens);
}

std::cout << "\n0s: " << numZeros << " Evens: " << numEvens << " Odds: " << numOdds << std::endl;
```

Comment: I would probably replace `whileLimit--` with `--whileLimit` and add 3 instead of 2 when initializing `whileLimit`... Otherwise, I would probably avoid `continue` and use `if (!whileValue) { ++numZeros; } else if (whileValue % 2) { ++numOdds; } else { ++numEvens; }` on multiple lines in a case like this one.